# SharePoint 2010 - Word .dot templates

Tags: word, document-template

I have created a SharePoint library that contains various Word .dot templates. Can I force Word to open a .doc file when clicking on the .dot file in the SharePoint library, as it would do if I double-clicked (or right-click and choose New) the .dot template in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

The normally suggested work-around for template documents is to set read-only rights to all users but one admin account (that will have full control).

This way, users will get a read only version of the item in word. If they edit and try to save, they will be forced to save as a new file.

Comment: Have tried that, but unfortunately if they save that way and change .dot to .doc, the document loses the template link and the embedded macros.

Comment: It sure does. Unfortunately there is no better way in SharePoint, to many peoples frustration